# How to import Vue multiselect in plain js file without CLI

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, vue-component, vue-cli

I wanna import vue multiselect in my Vue app which I made withhout cli. it's plain js and all the content are in my html. but I cannot import libraries like Vue Multiselect :(
In HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="app">
<multiselect v-model="value" tag-placeholder="Add this as new tag" placeholder="Search or 

add a tag" label="name" track-by="code" :options="options" :multiple="true" :taggable="true" @tag="addTag"></multiselect>
    </div>
<script src="../assets/js/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0"></script>

<script type="module" src="../assets/js/user-list.js">
</script>
</body>
```

In JS:

```
new Vue({
 data() { return {} }
}).$mount(#app)
```

I can't import it like how I used to in vue cli, like:

```
import multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'
```

and

```
components: { multiselect}
```

when I import, there's errors like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Error resolving module specifier “vue”. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like following snippet , with `components: { Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default }`:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default },
  data () {
    return {
      value: [],
      options: [
         {"name": "aaa", "id": "1",},
         {"name": "bbb", "id": "2",},
         {"name": "ccc", "id": "3",}
       ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css">
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <multiselect
    v-model="value"
    placeholder="chose"
    label="name" 
    track-by="id"
    :options="options"
    :multiple="true"
    :taggable="true"
  ></multiselect>
<pre>{{ value  }}</pre>
</div>
```